# Magento 2 Update Cart button is not display after customize Product page

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I have so much customization in product page of my website.everything is working fine on product page while when we go to cart page and click to edit any page it redirect to `

> websiteurl/checkout/cart/configure/id/366/product_id/2555/

and it still display add to cart button in place of "**update cart**" button.

I hit and try and replace whole `catalog_product_view.xml` in my theme with original xml file,now it display now.

One thing more:

Why it is using `catalog_product_view.xml` as per Magento standard it should call 
`checkout_cart_configure.xml`  file as per url.
Is anyone have idea which part is responsible for Update cart button on page "`checkout/cart/configure`"?

Please help me.